# Environment variables in ROS YAML file?

Tags: yaml, ros

Is there a way to use environment variables in a ROS yaml file that gets loaded during a launch file?

For example,

test.launch:

```
<launch>    
   <rosparam command="load" file="example.yaml" />
</launch>
```

example.yaml:

```
vehicle_name: "${VEHICLE_NAME}_robot"
```

I know that you could load the environment variable as a param in the launch file using the `<env>` or `<optenv>` tags, but when there are a lot of parameters, it's much neater to have them defined in a separate .yaml file. Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [rosparam](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) tag has an attribute `subst_value` to enable the `env`, `optenv`, etc. substitution args for the YAML text **when added directly in the launch file**. That is the following works:

```xml
<launch>
    <!-- works -->
    <rosparam subst_value="true">
        foo: $(env USER)
    </rosparam>
</launch>
```

For **ROS Kinetic and later**, it also works when using an external YAML file:

```xml
<launch>
    <rosparam file="/path/to/conf.yaml" subst_value="true" />
</launch>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, [roslaunch just uses PyYAML's `.load`](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/melodic-devel/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/loader.py#L101) and [PyYaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) does not support reading env variables in yaml files.

You could create multiple yaml files different names and load them selectively using env variables in launch files, for example:

```
<launch>    
   <rosparam command="load" file="$(optenv VEHICLE_NAME default_vehicle_name)_example.yaml" />
</launch>
```

`